# how to save images on a server (structure)

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-2, image-processing

I'm programming a application with mvc2. Users should be able to upload images to their profile.
The best way to save the images is to save them in a database, but I think it is the most expensive one too. (I'm using MSSql)
I thought the best way would be to save them on the server. I thought about: a User uploads images, the server resize them and save the Image on the server and the image-path in a database.

But what about if I do not have any more capacities on my server an I have to use a second one or third one?

**My question: what is the best way to handle images on a server? What is the best way to be flexible?**

Thanks for your answers!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of factors to consider.

The best way isn't necessarily storing images in a database.  That can be a good choice, especially if you want to implement access control on the images.  However, this comes at the cost of having to pull the image from the database and loading it into memory so that it can be streamed out by a server.

However, as these are profile images, and presumably visible by anyone who visits that user's profile, I'd advocate storing the file *as a file* on the server and storing a reference to that file in your database.

When it comes down to it, web servers are very good at serving files efficiently.  If you can make use of that, you should.

Finally, you have concerns about space.  In the first instance, you can prevent images of a certain size from being uploaded in the first place.  You can also, as you suggest, auto-crop to a selected size.

If sheer volume of users becomes a problem, you can always store your media on a separate server, storing a fully qualified link to each resource, eg :-

```
<img src="http://images2.mydomain.com/image/profile_123.png" alt="A profile pic" />
```

Comment: When storing images as files you also have plenty of access control options. Other than that, +1 I completely agree